# HTTP Status Code to use when declining to create a new entity because there's too many already created?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, http-status-codes, api-design

What HTTP Status Code should be used when a client submits an entity, but my server determines (through business logic) that the collection they're adding to is already full (like an event that they want to register for is at maximum occupancy already)?

Answer (score 1):

Since the **client** made a legit request, but it is the **server** that makes the request invald (through your business logic), I suppose you should use a 5XX code.

Probably what fits your requirements is

> 507 - Insufficent Storage

Have a look at the [RFC4918#11.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.5)